# How to set Tesseract 2 to read a SINGLE char in C#?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, image-recognition

Im writing a simple OCR in C# and im using tesseract 2.0

In my program i will recognize ONLY capital letters.

For this reason im using:

```
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

So at this point i will pass an image of a single capital letter.
It works quit good but sometimes it returns to me a string with TWO letters.

```
Input:
R
Output:
FE
```

Now i need to know how to set the page segmentation mode to "single character." to improve the results.

Anyone knows how to do this in C# with tesseract 2?

Becouse in the Tesseract ocr object i have only the SetVariable Methods.
In iOS apis there is this method to do this:

```
setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSM is only available in Tesseract 3.0x; therefore, you'll need a compatible .NET wrapper. There is one at https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract.

Comment: Thank You very much to reply at my question.

Simple, short and good answer.

Comment: with the above wrapper you have to call ```tesseract.Process(picture, Tesseract.PageSegMode.SingleChar);```